# Update excerpts in Chronicle Queue

Tags: chronicle-queue

we store events in Chronicle Queue V4 and have a tailer to process them. Some of those events expire (not time based, but by being superseded by a later event), and can thus be skipped during processing.

Is there a way to update an existing excerpt, i.e. set a boolean flag "expired" to true, so we can skip expired events? Or is there another solution to achieve this with Chronicle Queue?

For example, the system generates events A1, B1 and C1. Now an event B2 arrives, making B1 obsolete. We would now be able to skip B1 without expensive processing.

Regards,
Jochen

Answer (score 0):

**Analysis of your requirements**

1. You are writing events to the queue. Events have a unique key K.
2. while writing it is possible that the current event supersedes an older, already written event which the same key K.
3. you want to update the older, already written event with key K to tell a tailer (which comes later) that a newer version exists.

I think this is a pretty common requirement, and it looks attractive at first, but (as I experienced) it is flawed. Here is why:

It is helpful to assume that you are dealing with a large number of events, like 100s per second. Chronicle Queue is very much capable of this on modest hardware. For now I also assume that you just write to the queue, you don't record anything anywhere else regarding your data.

The crucial point is number 2 above: You are writing an event and you realize that you need to update an older event. What do you need to do? You need to scan the whole queue, potentially going back a long time / lots of events to search for the older event. Only then you can update it and be done with the new event. This does NOT scale.

**Potential solutions:**

1. Tailer needs to know all.
2. Index-based version map.

Tailer needs to know all:

I assume your tailer executes some action A on the data.
You let your tailer run through all events and execute A only after it has determined it has the newest version of the event with K.
Evaluation: The tailer needs either a full scan of the queue for each event, or it needs to build some data structure / map for each event key K.

Index based version Map

Your appender gets an index from Chronicle Queue when it writes the event. In a memory or file based based map (e.g. Chronicle Map, MapDB...), store the key K along with the latest index of the event. If the key is already in the map, it simply updates it. Now the tailer does NOT process the queue in order, but a component takes all keys from the map, seeks to the index, reads the event and executes A. Then it procedes to the next key.

**Things to think about**

How many events will the tailer be processing in a certain time frame? This will determine the map size: size of map: number of events per timeframe * (length of key + 64bit index number)

Maybe a continuous operation is better: Make Action A idempotent and repeatable: can run as often as you want, older versions never update a newer version of the event.

IMHO the index of Chronicle Queue is a very good tool and it's almost free :)